# How to test a drop down select that has a variable in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

I have a drop down select, most of them look like:

```
id="person_job_name"
```

This one has an artifact in it and I am not sure how to have the rails test find the drop down correctly, when I inspect the element on this page it looks like this:

```
id="person_people_job_attributes_12039485_class_id
```

the number changes each time.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't use [Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) in the Capybara select method, you can use them in a `within` block to find a select element with an id that **starts with person_people_job_attributes**.

This way the number on the end of that id can be anything and it will still find it

```
within "select[id^='person_people_job_attributes']" do
  select "some option"
end
```